COUNTIF across a column based on inequality
Id like to count the number of times that Column A is greater than or equal to Column B.
EG:



A
B




1
3


2
4


3
1


4
1


5
8



Which in this case would be two.
I've tried to use
=COUNTIF($A$2:$B$6, A2:A6 > B2:B6) 

but this doesn't work.

Greater than, or equal to, requires >=, what version of Excel do you have?

Try this:
=SUM(IF(A2:A6>=B2:B6,1,0))

All greater than or equals will result in 1, all less then will result in 0 and the result is counted.

Edit:
As stated by user11222393, 0 is not even required and this is even shorter: =SUM(N(A2:A6>=B2:B6))

No need for 0 in IF - =SUM(IF(A2:A6>=B2:B6,1)). =SUM(N(A2:A6>=B2:B6)) would be even shorter

@user11222393 thanks! Didn't even know the N function.

N(), --(), 1*() would work instead of IF in this case with N() being shortest
